# difference between He is and he's as answers to questions(or she is and she's)

Tags: difference

I have been wondering if there is any difference between He is and he's as answers to questions.Please consider the following sentences:

1. **A:How old is he?**
2. **B:he's five years old.**

Why is it not common to answer such questions with the "is" preceded by pronoun?

I and other people who have this exact question in mind would be very appreciated if someone provides an answer.

Answer (score 2):

They mean the same thing:  "he's" is a contraction of "he is."

"He's" is how it is usually spoken (at least in informal/conversational speech) and so "he's" is also frequently used in written dialogue.

In more formal writing you generally would use "he is" and not the contraction.

Comment: To add, "he is" would be the second part of the affirmative answer to a question.  You would never say, "Yes, he's", and always, "Yes, he is".  However, it's possible to use the contraction when there are words that follow.